# renaming a setup in c#

Tags: c#-2.0

i have a setpu in c:\3c\install\builds\output\ dir
having name setup.
i want to rename this setup from a c# file. please tell me how to rename this .
when i am tyring 
File.Move(c:\3c\install\builds\output\setup,c:\3c\install\builds\Renamesetup\newsetup);

it is giving file not found exception.

Could not find file 'c:\3c\install\builds\output\setup'.

please tell me what is wrong in it .

thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
File.Move("c:\\3c\\install\\builds\\output\\setup", "c:\\3c\\install\\builds\\Renamesetup\\newsetup");
```

This assumes that the file "setup" does not have an ".exe" extension. Also, the new file will not have an ".exe" extension.

The folder "Renamesetup" must exist in advance, otherwise you must create it in your code using `Directory.CreateDirectory`.

Please note that you have to "quote" the backslashes using "\\" as I've done above. This only works if "setup" is a file!

Answer (score 0):

The path makes it look like setup is a directory. If so you should use

```
System.IO.Directory.Move
```